# ARM Assembly accepting '-'

Tags: string, assembly, integer, arm, ascii

So my code currently converts a string into a integer. My code is currently working and functional however, i need it to accept an "-" at the beginning of the input to judge if it is a negative or not. I have no idea how to do this and i can not find any sources. I am currently passing in (test3:  .asciz "-48") into register r0. and when i run in the debugger i am receiving 45. here is my code for reference.

```
    .global stoi
    .text
stoi:
    push {r4,r5,r6,r8,r9,lr}
    @r0 = buffer
    mov r1,#0         @r1 = n = 0
    mov r9,#0         @buffer counter
    mov r4,#48        @0 checker
    mov r5,#57        @9 checker
    b 5f

5:
    ldrb r3,[r0,r9]      @r3 = c

    b 1f

1:
    cmp r3,r4         @cmp c to 0(48 in ASCII)
    bge 2f
    b 4f
2:
    cmp r3,r5       @cmp c to 9(57 in ASCII)
    ble 3f
    b 4f
3:
    sub r6,r3,#'0'      @r6 = (c - '0')
    @strb r6,[r0,r9]
    add r1,r1,r1,lsl#2  @r1 = n * 10
    add r1,r1,r1,lsl#0

    add r1,r1,r6        @n = n * 10 + (c - '0')

    add r9,r9,#1        @add to buffer
    b 5b

4:
    mov r0,r1
    pop {r4,r5,r6,r8,r9,pc}
```

Comment: Hint: Start by implementing the algorithm in a high-level language in which you are comfortable working, then gradually lower the reference implementation to roughly match the level and capabilities of the assembly code.

Comment: thanks for the advice,but i am new to the coding world and the only language iv learned so far is python. and that is a simple "int(string)".

Comment: My point is that assembly language details are a distraction from understanding the algorithm. Begin by sketching out the principle of how you would do it by hand in Python without utilizing the support functions, through a flow chart or some other method. Then sit down and implement the assembly code.

Comment: Even in python you can access separate characters of that string, and calculate value of `int` by yourself from the characters. So that may help you with logical structure of your asm algorithm, and if you are experienced with python and it's debugger, it may be easier for you to first do this to verify your algorithm works on high level.

Comment: Yes, per @Tommylee2k,  45 = 0x2D  = -      in ASCII

Answer (score 4):

use the same code you're using now, and add these changes:

1) skip the '-' if it's the first char. 
Right now you're stopping if a non-digit char is read, you receive 45 (in R3), it is the ascii of '-'. Afais R1 should still be 0 tho

2) At the end, add a check if the first char is a '-', and if it is, subtract r1 from 0 (since 0 - x is -x)

( 3) remove the b 1f, it's not needed ;) )

Comment: @Blake: More generally, clean up the other branching by inverting the branch conditions to a single branch-or-fall-through instruction, instead of skipping over a unconditional branch.  And use meaningful names for your branch labels, not just numbers.